# How to measure the scalability of all ways to deploy a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

There a few approachs to deploy a Shiny app:

[With Heroku](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-an-r-shiny-app-on-heroku-free-tier-b31003858b68)
or
[Using ShinyProxy, Traefik and Docker Swarm](https://www.databentobox.com/2020/05/31/shinyproxy-with-docker-swarm/)
or
[Shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/)
or
[Shiny Server](https://rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/)
or
[Replace Shiny UI by shiny.semantic](https://appsilon.com/how-we-built-a-shiny-app-for-700-users/)

Is well known that ShinyServer is very expensive and Shinyapps.io i'ts not scalable:
[image]

[Article](https://medium.com/@akpradhn/how-to-deploy-a-shiny-app-at-zero-cost-94e8897df34d)

But compare all the approachs, how to measure which is more cost efficient?

Comment: (1) This appears to have no content about "programming", entirely *"about professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration"* and therefore a better fit for https://serverfault.com. (2) Because the "cost" of things varies from user to user, this is very likely to be subjective (perhaps even "opinions", which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO). (3) Frankly, it sounds like a problem-statement for a ***great*** journal article (or the start of specifications for a contractor RFP). But I don't see it as a great fit for StackOverflow. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I have hosted apps using the three approaches listed in the table. On the basis of cost = time + money:

1. shinyapps.io: by far the cheapest, so long as it meets your needs.
2. shiny-server: takes longer to setup, requires a server, but fewer limitations.
3. ShinyProxy: takes even longer to setup, requires a server, experience with Docker, very capable.

The most cost-efficient option will be the first option in this list that meets all of your needs: (1) shinyapps.io, (2) shiny-server (free), (3) ShinyProxy, (4) Shiny-server Pro.

**Memory:** Shiny-server can share memory between multiple instances of the same app while each instance of a ShinyProxy app is completely independent. Many instances of an app that demands a lot of memory will drain your server resources faster if it is hosted using ShinyProxy vs Shiny-server.

**CPU:** Multiple instances of the same app will share the same R instance and processor thread in Shiny-server. So many concurrent users may experience a slowdown of a compute-heavy app when hosted using Shiny-server. In ShinyProxy, each user will get their own Docker container/app which could be distributed between multiple processors, supporting better scaling of compute-heavy apps.

**Authentication:** Authentication only supported by ShinyProxy (or Shiny-server Pro)

**Shiny-server Pro:** (paid) allows you to optimize between CPU and memory, provides authentication, user monitoring, etc., but includes a subscription cost.

**Actually measuring/testing app scalability:** Use *shiny load test* (see https://rstudio.github.io/shinyloadtest/ for more details).